# Write a list of strings in a list that may or may not contain commas to a csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I am scraping a table from a website and building a list of strings by  looping.  My code works great until there is a comma in one of the values.

This is how I'm building the list (looping structure omitted, clearly):

```
record = (name, availability, upc, price)
productList.append(",".join(item or "" for item in record))
```

This results in:

```
[u'Product One, In Stock, 999999999999, $99.99', u'Product Two, In Stock, ....]
```

Which I then write to a CSV with:

```
import unicodecsv as csv

...

f = open('data.csv', 'wb')
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
w.writerow([x.split(',') for x in productList])
f.close()
```

Which works great right up until there is a comma in one of the product names.  Not surprisingly, at that point it chops the product name into multiple columns.

Comment: @UrielEli: That just means if a tilde appears in the field normally, it gets converted to a comma on read. The solution is to let the `csv` module do its job so it handles quoting for you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger:  Thanks!  I implemented your suggested edit to productList.append as well as the adjustment to the writing section of code.  (Once my fat-fingered typos were fixed) It worked like a champ!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop manually adding and removing commas yourself. That's why the `csv`/`unicodecsv` modules exist, because you'll get stuff like quoting wrong.

When building your rows, make them plain sequences (`list`s or `tuple`s) of the fields, not the whole row as a single string:

```
productList.append([item or "" for item in record])
# If the or "" is to handle Nones only, module already handles this, so you can simplify:
productList.append(record)
```

When writing the rows, they're already in the correct form, so no splitting needed:

```
with open('data.csv', 'wb') as f
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
    w.writerows(productList)
    # writerows call is just faster way to do:
    # for row in productList: w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: If I had know the right response would come so quick I'd have asked it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

In your `record` variable you already have a tuple, right?

Instead of adding to the `productList` a string that you create joining the values in that tuple, just add the tuple itself:

```
record = (name, availability, upc, price)
productList.append(record)
```

And then, use the `writerow` method of the `unicodecsv` writer to write directly the tuple in the file. In the example shown in the [packages's web page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1) it is showing how to write a tuple. The package will take care of wrapping the strings that contain a comma with quotation marks.

```
import unicodecsv as csv

productList = [
    (u'Product One', u'In Stock', 999999999999, u'$99.99'),
    (u'Product,Two', u'In Stock', 1234, u'$5.00'),
    (u'Product Three', u'In Stock', 5678, u'$7.99'),
]

with open("foo.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
    for product in productList:
        w.writerow(product)
```

This produces a proper `foo.csv`:

```
$ cat foo.csv
Product One,In Stock,999999999999,$99.99
"Product,Two",In Stock,1234,$5.00
Product Three,In Stock,5678,$7.99
```

(see how `"Product,Two"` has been properly wrapped with `"`?)